# Calling makepkg from an outer directory

Tags: linux, archlinux, package-managers

I realized that when I try to call `makepkg` command on a `PKGBUILD` in an inner file, for instance `makepkg package_name/PKGBUILD`, I get an error saying

> ==> ERROR: PKGBUILD does not exist.

But when I change my current directory to the directory of `PKGBUILD` file, `cd package_name`, and run `makepkg PKGBUILD` I face no problems. So, is it true that I have to strictly be in the `PKGBUILD` file's directory to be able to call `makepkg`on it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that way. If you are scripting this and want to avoid switching folders back and forth, an option can be to utilize a sub-shell like this

```
(cd package_name && makepkg PKGBUILD)
```

which will then transport you back to current folder after finishing the actions within the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

The command `makepkg PKGBUILD` does not do what you think it does. makepkg does *not* accept the name of a PKGBUILD as a positional parameter, and it completely discards this entirely.

As per the manpage, if you wish to specify a PKGBUILD to use, you must use the `-p <buildscript>` option. Also as per the manpage, "The buildscript must be located in the directory makepkg is called from."

```
$ makepkg -p package_name/PKGBUILD
==> ERROR: package_name/PKGBUILD must be in the current working directory.
```

As you can see, makepkg contains code to ensure you don't try doing something which it does not allow you to do -- but you **must** correctly use the makepkg command-line options in order for makepkg to recognize what you're trying to do and tell you what you did wrong.